# Ajax, jQuery, Django. How does this get setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Here is my view:

```
def planning(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))

    if request.is_ajax:
        POST = request.POST
        msg = "Success"
        print request.POST
        return HttpResponse(msg)
    else:
        form = planForm()
        return render(request, 'plan.html', {'form':form})
```

Here is my html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Plan{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <a>Welcome to planning</a>
    {{form.as_p}}
    <script>
     <----- I need to know how to set this up ---->
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I understand I need to make a button that when clicked submits my form but from the examples I've seen on the internet it isn't very intuitive. Can someone example to me how I would get a button on this page to send the ajax call out to the server.

EDIT:
How do I hook this up to a button?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Plan{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <a>Welcome to planning</a>
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button id="form_submit">Submit</button>
    <script>
        $('button#form_submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"/planning/submit/",
            data: {
                'test': 'success',
            },
            success: function(){
                alert('test')
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to implement this, but here's one, keeping in mind you don't have much control over the `<form>` attributes:

You'd make a button like this:

```
<button id="form_submit">Submit</button>
```

Then, within the `<script>` tag, something like (using some jQuery):

```
$('button#form_submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/planning/submit/",
        data: $("#form_id").serialize(),
        success: function(){
            alert('test')
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
    });
});
```

Looks like you were just missing the last `});`, and you should serialize the form data to send it (replace `form_id` with your form's id).

Comment: request.is_ajax != request.method == 'POST': That is it's not working with $.post

Comment: See updated answer. Looks like you were just missing an end to the code block.